# crm online trouble from updating related lookup field when transaction changed

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

I work with Crm online.
When I create opportunity entity recording I want set pricelevel programmaticaly (from plugin). But if I set pricelevel with another transactioncurrencyid, it will not set. Even I change transactioncurrency from opportunity with pricelevel, changes only transaction currency.
This is why set of enabled value in pricelevel lookup depends on opportunity transactioncurrency field.
How can I set set pricelevel with another transactioncurrencyid from plugin?
Has anybody such troubles?

Comment: Is the plugin pre-operation?

Comment: I tried add plugin on pre operation. After this I tied add plugin to post create and set currency -> update -> set pricelevel-> update. The result is the same. After this I tried remove update pricelevel logic to Custom action. The result is the same.
Trouble is from form: enabled set at the moment of setting pricelevel is another. This is why value not setted on lookup and write message Exist not saved changes from bottom (but when I refresh, this message removed and lookup don't set).

Comment: Only decision that I now - do it on js. Get pricelevel from custom action -> compare currency -> set currency to pricelevelcurrency -> refresh -> update lookup